# T-SQL Conditional Select Across Tables

Tags: t-sql, sqlite

I have a table (lets call it main_guys) that looks like:

```
id, other_item_id, other_item_type, another_column, group_id
```

The `other_item_type` tells me which additional table holds additional information identified by the `other_item_id`.

Additional columns required in the query depends on the table identified by `other_item_type`. So for `other_item_type == 'Type-X'` I need to get values from columns `foo` and `bar` from the `X` table. While for `other_item_type == Type-Y` I need to get values from columns `ick and blah` from `Y table`.

In a perfect world, I would be able to get something like:

`id, other_item_id, other_item_type, another_column, group_id, foo, bar, ick, blah` - with values filled in where needed per type and other columns being null or what not if not needed.

One additional issue is that `other_item_type` and `other_item_id` can also be empty - and the rest of the columns in that row need to be returned in the select - but in the empty case none of the additional columns across the other tables should contain any values.

In terms of pseudo-code...

```
// obviously not proper code - just trying to communicate need
// Note: Need all items from main_guys table - 
// even if main_guys.other_item_type is empty
select * from main_guys where main_guys.group_id == "12345" 
if main_guys.other_item_type == "Type-X"
 select x.foo, x.bar from x where x.id == main_guys.other_item_id
else if main_guys.other_item_type == "Type-Y" 
 select y.ick, y.bar from y where y.id == main_guys.other_item_id
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s

```
select * from main_guys MG
    left outer join X 
       on MG.id=X.other_item_id and other_item_type='Type-X'

    left outer join Y 
       on MG.id=Y.other_item_id and other_item_type='Type-Y'
    where MG.group_id = '12345' --not sure why this is text
```

Comment: Sadly - the database I'm reading from is not under my control - thus the string based id :( ... Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this

```
SELECT mg.id, mg.other_item_id, mg.other_item_type, coalesce(x.ick, y.ick)
FROM main_guys mg
     LEFT OUTER JOIN x ON x.id = mg.Other_Item_ID AND mg.Other_Item_Type = 'Type-X'
     LEFT OUTER JOIN y ON y.id = mg.Other_Item_ID AND mg.Other_Item_Type = 'Type-Y'
```

If I understand you correctly it would mean you have a reference to two (or more) tables in one column of a master table. I would encourage you to change the design of the master table to have ***one column*** having ***one meaning***.

Comment: I think that the id columns are the otherway round. X, Y have other_item_id.

Comment: yeah - totally agree about the design issue ... sadly - I'm using the a store not under my control. Thanks for the solution. Good Stuff.

Comment: @pjp: not according to OP's pseudo code but considering that he already has accepted your answer, you are probably right.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT m.*, x.*, y.*
FROM main_guys m
    LEFT JOIN x ON m.id=x.other_item_id AND m.other_item_type = 'Type-X'
    LEFT JOIN y ON m.id=y.other_item_id AND m.other_item_type = 'Type-Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be create set on unions with hardcoded other_item_type values as you have

```
select * from 
(
    select main.*, x.foo as col1, x.bar as col2
    from main_guys as main
    inner join x on x.id == main_guys.other_item_id
    where other_item_type == "Type-X"
    union
    select main.*, y.ick as col1, y.bar as col2
    from main_guys as main
    inner join y on y.id == main_guys.other_item_id
    where other_item_type == "Type-Y" 
) as a
```

It depends how many distinct values of other_item_type you have and how many want to handle.

Comment: pjp - you are tough. message was saved accidentally. Try tab+enter!

Comment: Ok :) Why do you need the outer select?